# Prove that $F$ is closed if every point $x \in X$ has an open neighborhood $V$ s.t. $F \cap V$ is a closed subset of $V$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Suppose $F$ is a subset of a topological space $X$. Prove that $F$ is closed if every point $x \in X$ has an open neighborhood $V$ s.t. $F \cap V$ is a closed subset of $V$.

Proof:

Let $x \in X$. Then, by hypothesis, $\exists$ open hood' $V \subset X$ such that $F \cap V$ is closed in $V$.

Since $F \cap V$ is a closed subset of $V$, $\exists$ closed hood' $W \subset X$ such that $W \cap V = F \cap V$.

We then have $W = F$, and thus $F$ is closed.

EDIT: Of course I errored and it is not true that $W \cap V = F \cap V \rightarrow W = F$. Can somebody help me fix this proof?

Comment: Your conclusion that $W \cap V = F \cap V \implies W=F$ is not correct

Comment: Hmmm.. you are correct... Dang.

Comment: It would be nice if you included what definitions youre working with. What is a closed set? When are sets in a subspace closed?

Comment: A set is closed if it has all its limit points, or equivalently if it's complement is open. A set $F$ is closed in subspace $V \subset X$ if $\exists$ a closed $U \subset X$ s.t. $U \cap V = F$.

Comment: The set $W$ depends on $V$, there is no way to prove that $W=F$.

Comment: Note that the left to right implication also holds: if $F$ is closed let $V=X\setminus F$ for $x \notin F$ (which is open and $V \cap F = \emptyset$ is closed in $F$) and $V=X$ when $x \in F$ (as $F$ is closed in $F$ too). Quite trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an arbitrary $x\in X \setminus F$. By hypothesis, there is an open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $F\cap V$ is closed in $V$. Since $x\notin F$, then $x\notin F\cap V$. So there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $(U\cap V) \cap (F \cap V) = \emptyset$, or $U \cap V \cap F = \emptyset$.  As $U\cap V$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ disjoint from $F$, it follows that $X\setminus F$ is open, i.e., $F$ is closed.

Comment: So you used the fact that $(F \cap V)^c$ is open in $V$ to get the open hood $U$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.